# Avoiding the default '\n' with cout

Tags: c++

```
cout<<"\nEnter Date of Birth";
cin>>date;
cout<<"-";
cin>>month;
cout<<"-";
cin>>year;
```

In this code, I want the input to be taken as `25-02-1994`(the dashes appear automatically after the preceding value is entered).But,instead a '`\n`' is appended automatically and the input is taken as

```
Enter Date of Birth25
('\n')-02
('\n')-1994
```

I had to mark ('`\n`') to mark that the dashes appear on a new line.Any suggestions??

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15425107/line-spacing-after-endl-and-cout

Comment: Why not input an entire line instead, and parse it based on the location of the dashes?

Comment: That's the behaviour of pressing enter in your console while inputting, not `std::cout`.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for low-level keystroke console interaction, and if so, there is no standard language or library support for such requirements. There are per-platform solutions, but thats about as good as you're going to get. This assuming it appears you want `'-'` to emit as soon as the user enters two digits, then again after two more, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you hit enter. It's normal. If you don't want the '\n' character, remove it.

```
date [ strlen( date ) - 1] = '\0';
month[ strlen( month) - 1] = '\0';
year [ strlen( year ) - 1] = '\0';
```